# Call to undefined function mysql_query() with Login

Tags: php, mysqli

When i execute my **PHP** code below i get a **Fatal error** and i'm not sure how to resolve it.

Thank you for your help

**The Error**

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lprapp/config.php:23
>   Stack trace:#0 {main}
>     thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lprapp/config.php on line 23

**Code**

```
    <?php

    $user = 'root';
    $password = 'root';
    $db = 'inventory';
    $host = 'localhost';
    $port = 8888;

    $link = mysqli_init();
    $success = mysqli_real_connect(
       $link,
       $host,
       $user,
       $password,
       $db,
       $port
    );

    ?>
    <?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."' and password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
    $row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($rom > 0 )
    {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
      $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
      echo "login done";
    }else {
      echo "fail login ";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Obligatory advice: Don't use mysql. Upgrade to mysqli at the very least. The environment you're on might actually use mysqli already; thus the error.

Comment: You can't mix and match mysqli_* and mysql_* APIs

Comment: @JonStirling Oh, you're right. I missed the top half of his code.

Comment: thank you  Carcigenicate

Comment: `Call to undefined function mysql_query()` I'm guessing you're running PHP 7 where the `mysql_` extension isn't merely deprecated but has been removed completely.

Comment: `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`. Welcome to 2016.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are mixing mysql and mysqli

Change these lines:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."' and password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
$row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

to

```
$sql = mysqli_query($success, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."' and password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

Comment: Please note that this code is **wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks**, allowing basically anyone to view and modify your database. Instead of simply changing the API, please consider using **prepared statements** instead. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/479156) on how you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the deprecated [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Try something like:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($success, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."' and password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your PHP version? [Extension "Mysql" was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).
Use extension Mysqli (like mysqli_query).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that start using mysqli_() and stop using mysql_()

Check the following page: [LINK](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

> Warning
> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed
> in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be
> used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
> information. Alternatives to this function include:
> mysqli_affected_rows() PDOStatement::rowCount()

Try and use [mysqli_()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) Or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)